# Как отслеживать поворот обьекта?

Tags: unity3d

мне для игры нужно сделать скример когда стоишь в триггере и поворачиваешься на определенную разницу координат поворота, например если обьект повернут в области от 40 до 90 градусов.
я хотел сделать это прописав два скрипта триггера, один скрипт когда стоишь в триггере включает триггер для 3д курсора(меш который поварачивается за камерой в центре экрана) и если в триггер войдет этот курсор то значит определенный поворот соблюден, и значит можно включать скример, но это так сложно и душно, легче прописать пару строчек отслеживания поворота, так что помогите, мне нужно отслеживать ось по y, и если что когда стоишь в триггере то включается bool на тру, и отслеживается именно значение bool в ифе, буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angle = transform.localEulerAngles.z;
angle = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
angle = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

//P.s. Я сам начинающий, может это подтолкнет
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, ответ на вопрос должен быть **исчерпывающим**. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1520667/edit)».